# Get values in tkinter entry under same name

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, tkinter-entry

I currently have a function which creates 2 entry boxes when a button is clicked. The values of these entry boxes need to be entered into a database. The problem with this is that every time the button is clicked the entry boxes have the same name as the ones before. This means that if the button is clicked twice then when it is being submitted into the database only the values in the last set of boxes are entered in. This is the code:

```
    def new(self):
    global ExerciseCount
    ExerciseCount = ExerciseCount + 1
    print (ExerciseCount)
    for num in range(ExerciseCount):
        self.Exercises = Entry(self.FrameExercise, bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"),  width = 20)
        self.Exercises.grid(row=2+ExerciseCount, column=1)

    global WeightCount
    WeightCount = WeightCount + 1
    print (WeightCount)
    for num in range(WeightCount):
        self.Weights = Entry(self.FrameExercise, bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"),  width = 4)
        self.Weights.grid(row=2+WeightCount, column=2)


def Update(self):
    global MemberID

    connection = sqlite3.connect(r"F:\TESTING\Program\Accounts.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    Exercise = self.Exercises.get()
    Weight = self.Weights.get()
    ID = self.ent_MemberID.get()

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Exercises (Exercise, Weight, ID) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    (Exercise, Weight, ID,))

    connection.commit()
```

When the button is clicked only the last set of entry boxes are submitted to the database. This could be down to me using `.get()` to retrieve the values from the entry, however I do not know any alternatives to this as I am still only a student. 
I have also tried to iterate the entry boxes by assigning a number to them however it appears with an error saying that a function cannot be assigned.

If there is any way to get the values in every entry box I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the text boxes in an array when you create them. Then use the array to access them. Here is an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
class MyApplication(tk.Frame):
    arr = []

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def addTextBox(self,event):
        newtext = tk.Entry(self)
        self.arr.append(newtext)
        newtext.pack()

    def getValues(self,event):
        for i in range(len(self.arr)):
            print self.arr[i].get()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.btnAdd = tk.Button(self)
        self.btnAdd["text"] = "Add"
        self.btnAdd.bind("<Button-1>", self.addTextBox)
        self.btnAdd.pack()  

        self.btnGet = tk.Button(self)
        self.btnGet["text"] = "Get"
        self.btnGet.bind("<Button-1>", self.getValues)
        self.btnGet.pack()  

# main
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width=325, height=325)
root.maxsize(width=325, height=325)
app = MyApplication(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I cannot use an array as the list may change in size if the user adds more exercises.

Comment: You don't have to specify a size (see my example). The append() function will increase the size of the array as needed.

Comment: HI, the problem is that I need to get the list of entries under one variable for example `Exercise` to use in the query. At the minute `.get()` is only accessing the last entry

Comment: Look at the way I call get() above. Since all the text boxes are in the array, you can loop through the array and call get() on each one. If you are going to have multiple text boxes, then you will need to call get() on each one. Storing them in an array makes it easier to do that, since you can use the array name and vary the index.